# Xamarin forms I can't upload multiple images to server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am developing an application and I have the following problem. I have to upload images to a server, but it has to be a background upload. With iOS (UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask (() => {});) I have had no problems and I have managed to send up to 300 images (they are appraisal images so I speak of at least 100 images) but on Android it always gives problems. I have a ForegroundService to run the loading process but like I say on Android it returns an error with sockets or it freezes and doesn't follow the process. I have tried to send the images sequentially (ERROR), I have sent them 5 by 5 with a recursive method, seeing which ones fail and resending them (up to 3 attempts), I have tried a var tasks = new List (); -> Task t = Task.WhenAll (tasks); and neither, I have tried with Parallel but again the sockets problem and now I am trying to send them with MultipartFormDataContent grouping them from 5 to 5 (content.Add (new StreamContent (item.imageStream), "...", ". .. ");) and, as always, iOS sends me without problems but in Android there is no way.

Do you know how I can do it to be able to send them? Is there a default limitation in Android that does not allow to upload so many images?

I send the images in base64 except in the last attempt at MultipartFormDataContent that passed the image stream.

Comment: For anyone to give you useful help, please **show your code**. Start with the SEQUENTIAL approach - that should be easiest to figure out what is going wrong. Are you sure you WAITED for each one to be done, before starting the next send?

Comment: Have you read Android docs re [Foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services), [Background taks](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#categories_of_background_tasks), and [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)?

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  There is no way for us to help you if you don't show the code that you're using.  You also mention "problems" and "errors" without telling us what **specific errors** or problems you're having.